# Wordpress Ratio Theme. Blog content needs to be centered

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I used Ratio theme of wordpress. My blog post texts and images are not aligned center. And I want to make it mobile responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS for this.
Like select class of that blog and apply CSS for text-align - center.
.blog { text-align: center;}
If you are not able to do this provide me link.